# Unable to send unix mail during shutdown/reboot

Tags: perl, email, unix, postfix-mta, system-administration

We have a perl script which tries to send an email notification when the system is about to shut down. To do this, we catch the SIGTERM and call Unix mail command to send email in the signal handler. SIGTERM is caught but the unix mail log shows that the FROM and TO address are changed from user@companyname.com to user@hostname during shutdown. Any idea why the system does this and how to prevent it? (Please note: The same email works fine when we run the script and kill the process from terminal)

**Here is the perl code snippet:**

```
$SIG{TERM} = \&signal_handler;

sleep(3600);

sub signal_handler { 

my $email_address = 'user@companyname.com';

system("echo \"TestBody\" | mail -s \"TestEmailSubject\" -c \"$email_address\" -r \"$email_address\" \"$email_address\"");

}
```

**Here is what is printed in /var/log/mail/mail during shutdown:**

```
Sep 17 21:17:04 postfix/postfix-script[7009]: starting the Postfix mail system

Sep 17 21:17:10 postfix/master[7011]: daemon started -- version 2.10.1, configuration /etc/postfix

Sep 17 21:17:10 postfix/pickup[10349]: 35F801809C9: uid=0 from=root

Sep 17 21:17:10 postfix/cleanup[10356]: 35F801809C9: message-id=<20190917211710.35F801809C9@HOSTNAME.net>

Sep 17 21:17:10 postfix/qmgr[10350]: 35F801809C9: from=root@HOSTNAME.net, size=1618, nrcpt=1 (queue active)

Sep 17 21:17:10 postfix/local[10372]: 35F801809C9: to=root@HOSTNAME.net, orig_to=<root>, relay=local, delay=13, delays=13/0.01/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to file: /dev/null)
```

**Here is the working case when we kill the process from terminal:**

```
Sep 17 21:20:41 postfix/pickup[10349]: E5328180968: uid=14936 from=user@COMPANYNAME.com

Sep 17 21:20:41 postfix/cleanup[22690]: E5328180968: message-id=<5d814e29.qZd+wgg47afpUdbd%user@COMPANYNAME.com>

Sep 17 21:20:41 postfix/qmgr[10350]: E5328180968: from=user@COMPANYNAME.com, size=544, nrcpt=1 (queue active)

Sep 17 21:20:41 postfix/smtp[22692]: E5328180968: to=user@COMPANYNAME.com, delay=0.06, delays=0.01/0/0/0.05, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 4E/77-59832-92E418D5)
```

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the email showing in the logs is the email generated by the perl script, and not an email generated by the system (e.g. a shutdown alert message? Note that the two "size"s are completely different. It's quite possible that your perl script is failing to generate an email during shutdown because postfix has already shut down

Comment: Dave, I added "service postfix status" in my script before and after sending the mail command to ensure that postfix is active/running.

Comment: That still doesn't answer the question of whether that log is displaying your email or another.

Comment: In the case of killing process from terminal (working case), logs show the correct email address. In the case of shutting down, logs show root@<HOSTNAME>.net which is not correct. Infact that is my question why the system does this. Also checked to ensure that postfix is active around that time.

Comment: You are still making the assumption that the email appearing in the logs is the email generated by your script. You have no proof of this. Try modifying your script so it skips sending the email, shut the system down, and see if you still get a logged email.

Comment: You are right, I modified the script to skip the email, but the mail log still shows mail activity with root@HOSTNAME.net which implies it is system generated.

Comment: But during shutdown, I also print the postfix status in our logs which shows that it is active/running

Comment: @DaveMitchell Do you have any suggestion here?

Answer (score 0):

the postfix system is probably being shut down earlier in the shutdown process than your script. Have you confirmed within your script that the mail system is still up *after* your script has tried to send an email?